# position 2 divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have my div inside an html like below,

```
<div class="mainBlock">
    <div style="display: inline-block"> 
        <span>This Text-1 may be a bit lengthy</span>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-left:50px">                    
        <span>This Text-2 may be a bit lengthy</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks on my UI: [image]

It has plenty of space to expand. 
The problem is, if the text in first div is short, the right div gets moved towards left (which is pretty obvious)

Now, what i require is the left side div should take some fixed width so that the right div will always be positioned at some fixed location.

Please advice the changes that needs to be done.

P.S. I want to avoid giving fixed width. I tried giving width of 50% to each div, but it isn't helping much.

Comment: Why isn't giving a 50% width helping?

Comment: use min-width, otherwise you're always going to have some kind of changes to the width

Comment: Why so many answers are marked down (-1). i think not all of them deserve a -1.

Comment: @A.R. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308184/answer-stealing-user-with-bad-attitude?noredirect=1#comment259270_308184 for the reason of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two divs side by side - Fluid display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As showed in my comment and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/be6uvg8z/)

Using `box-sizing: border-box;` will fix a lot of your problems, you can read more about it here: [Box Sizing Border Box FTW - Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Using a width of 50%, floating and **clearing the floats** will do perfectly fine and will work responsively (mobiles, tablets) as well.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Content, al lot of content. LOTS of content. Wow, this is asdf asd asd asd</div>
  <div class="column">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [flexbox](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/)...maybe will resolve your issue. I use the [grow](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/) technique.

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.flex-item {
    -webkit-flex: none;
    flex: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">This Text-1 may be a bit lengthy</div>
    <div class="flex-item">This Text-2 may be a bit lengthy</div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/18/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
<div class="mainBlock">
    <div style="display: inline-block;min-width:200px"> 
        <span>This Text-2 may be a bit lengthy</span>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-left:50px">                    
        <span>This Text-2 may be a bit lengthy</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLqeqxxm/2/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block` or `float: left`, as you prefer

**inline-block way:**

```
.mainBlock > div {
    width: calc(50% - 2px);
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

I have used a `calc(50% - 2px)` because for some reason if you use `width: 50%` the divs will appear in different lines because the browser render white spaces between each div in your html file and then they have not enough space (I think that's the reason. If you build your html content using javascript you can use `with: 50%` and it will work, because there are no white spaces between div elements).

**float way:**

```
.mainBlock > div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

You also could use display: flex but it won't work in IE9/IE10

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using inline-block property you should float both `divs` left
`style="float:left"` and use same `margin` property you have used in your html.

Instead of using inline css try using external or embedded css styling.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a percentage based width, or `min-width`?

I think percentage width will work fine.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaOgmx

Answer (score 0):

You can add fixed with to both the divs and also add float left to all the divs. It will help you achieve what you want.

```
<div class="mainBlock" style="float: left;">
    <div style="width: 500px; float: left;"> 
        <span>This Text-1 may be a bit lengthy</span>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 500px; float: left;">                    
        <span>This Text-2 may be a bit lengthy</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But you're not clearing any of your floats.. The rest of the page would break instantaneously