# How do I place 2 <div>s side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, chart.js

Hello I wrote this code using javascript, chart.js and html & css :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id = "Global">
<div id = "right">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<div id = "left">
<script>
var ctx = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
/*         labels: [18.123,46.8603108462,75.5976216923,104.334932538] */
        datasets: [{
            data: [{'y': 426777.148122,'x': 18.123},
{'y': 258927.721326,'x': 46.8603108462},
{'y': 176174.771954,'x': 75.5976216923},
{'y': 129604.15967,'x': 104.334932538},
{'y': 101328.238625,'x': 133.072243385}],
            label: "Model",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false     
        }, {
            label : 'Data',
            fill:false,
            showLine: false,
            backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
            data : [{x: 17.0, y: 454995.091169},
{x: 18.0, y: 457656.874749},
{x: 19.0, y: 444574.49162},
{x: 20.0, y: 432511.514968},
{x: 21.0, y: 421184.776328},
{x: 22.0, y: 410452.691467}],
                        type: 'line'
        }]        
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display: true,
            text:"Tools"
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic',
                position: 'bottom'
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic'
            }]
        }
    }
})
</script>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Actually when I look at the result in a browser I see the javascript above the 
`<div id = "right">` whereas I would like to have the javascript at the left and the `<div id = "right">` at the right.

Here is my css :

```
#Global
{
    width:100%;
}
#Global #left {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}
#Global #right {
    margin-left:60%   
}
```

I thought It will work but it is not the case.

Thank you for your help !

This is why I get when I look at the result in a browser :

[image: result]

Comment: Add float:right; to your #Global #right CSS

Comment: use inline-block

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_span1

Comment: Or even `float:left`. FYI since you are using `id` selectors, you can get rid of `#Global` in the second and third selectors.

Comment: Should the `<canvas>` be in the `<head>` section? I'd think it should be in the `<body>`. Also, how do you "see the javascript above"? Does the code show on the page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+two+divs+side+by+side

Comment: Canvas should be in the body, yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two divs side by side - Fluid display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display)

Answer (score -1):

Another option, aside from the ones already provided, would be to make your Global div a table instead and your left and right divs can be sibling cells in a row on that table.