# Divs not appearing side by side despite following online example

Tags: html, css

I've been looking up a solution to fixing an issue about 2 divs I have not appearing side by side. It's confusing because I feel like I've been doing exactly what I've seen in several examples found online. 
Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display) StackOverflow post.

What is it I'm missing?

Thanks!

```
<section class = "container">
    <div id="googleMap">
      <script src="redacted-for-privacy-of-group"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="showInfo">
      <img id="customerIMG" style="width: 100%">
      <p style="width: auto; height: auto" id="customerINFO"></p>
    </div>
 </section>
```

css

```
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#googleMap {
  width: 70%;
  height: 400px;
}

#showInfo {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 70%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Div are the block level elements. It will take all available  space. You need to use flex properly of CSS.

Comment: I think you are missing the key ingredient in the link you provide.. the float: left;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<section class = "container">
    <div id="googleMap">
      <script src="redacted-for-privacy-of-group"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="showInfo">
      <img id="customerIMG" style="width: 100%">
      <p style="width: auto; height: auto" id="customerINFO"></p>
    </div>
 </section>
```

css

```
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#googleMap {
  width: 70%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}

#showInfo {
  background-color: white;
  /*margin-left: 70%;*/
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **float: left;**

```
#googleMap {
  width: 70%;
  height: 400px;
  float:left;
}
```