# Trying to bring 2 different divs side by side

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, material-ui

Here is the code:

```
<Grid
  container
  justify="space-between"
  alignItems="flex-start"
  direction="column"
  xs
  spacing={5}
  style={{
    padding: 10,
  }}>
<ParamSelection/>
{
    state.selected != -1 && <Grid
      container
      item
      justify="space-between"
      alignItems="left"
      direction="column"
      spacing={5}
      style={{width:'350px', marginLeft: '10px'}}>
      <DatePickerView/>
}
```

Inside Param selection again a grid.

```
<Grid
  item
  container
  justify="flex-start"
  alignItems="left"
  direction="column"
  xs
  style={{width: '350px', marginLeft: '10px'}}
>
  <Grid item >
    <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="left">Select parameter for graph: </Typography>
  </Grid>
```

Currently it's showing like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I want select date to be on the same line as select parameter for graph, side by side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two divs side by side - Fluid display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display)

Comment: I have already tried float: left but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put both gird-elements in a div and add `display:flex` to the new-div.

```
<div class="parent"> <gird>element1</grid><grid>element2</grid>
```

style:

```
.parent{display:flex;};
```