# Border around Markdown embed in RMarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, markdown, pkgdown

I have a couple of Github profile "cards" created from [here](https://metrics.lecoq.io/embed) which I am embedding as Markdown in a RMarkdown page on a pkgdown website.

How would i go about adding a border to these? Anything i have found searching has been about using CSS or html to add borders to images rather than embeds like this.

Or alternatively change the background colour of them - they are white on a white page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix markdown and html code and even use `css` code chunks in your RMarkdown document to change the styling.  In the document below, I put the metrics card in a div with `class=bordered` and then changed the `border-style` attribute for the `bordered` class:

---

````
title: "test"
output: html_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
    
```{css echo=FALSE}
.bordered{
  border-style: solid;
}
```

<div class="bordered">
![](https://metrics.lecoq.io/davidaarmstrong?template=classic&base=header%2C%20activity%2C%20community%2C%20repositories%2C%20metadata&base.indepth=false&base.hireable=false&base.skip=false&config.timezone=America%2FToronto)
</div>
````

Here's the result:

[image]

---

#### side-by-side

To put two side-by-side: you could use a flexbox strategy:

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 50%;
  margin:15px; 
  border-style: solid;
}

.right {
  flex: 50%;
  margin:15px; 
  border-style: solid;
}
```

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">
![](https://metrics.lecoq.io/davidaarmstrong?template=classic&base=header%2C%20activity%2C%20community%2C%20repositories%2C%20metadata&base.indepth=false&base.hireable=false&base.skip=false&config.timezone=America%2FToronto)
</div>
<div class="right">
![](https://metrics.lecoq.io/davidaarmstrong?template=classic&base=header%2C%20activity%2C%20community%2C%20repositories%2C%20metadata&base.indepth=false&base.hireable=false&base.skip=false&config.timezone=America%2FToronto)
</div>
</div>
````

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does work. Now I'm having trouble with layout. I'm trying to have two of these, each bordered, and aligned side-by-side on the page (and centred). I've tried playing with other CSS options but not having much luck.

Comment: I did try creating a new style with `align-items: center;` and wrapping both embeds in that, but it made a total mess of the entire page so I'm definitely doing something wrong!

Comment: @hokeybot I just updated the answer with a possible solution.  This employs a slightly modified version of a suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display).

Comment: Thanks again. Works perfectly. I got very close with my own experimentation but not quite there!

I added this to the CSS for both to pretty it up a little. 

   `border-color: grey; border-radius: 12px; padding: 10px;`