CSS borders next to each other
I did a site with buttons within borders (mostly for practice), the issue with this is I don't know how to place these borders side by side as I want, only one under another. I'm still very new to CSS, so none of the answers I found were specific enough.


html,
body {
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #038253;
}

.border {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.border-2 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
<h1>Test Site</h1>
<!-- Button Group 1 -->
<div class="border">
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 3</button>
</div>

<!-- Button Group 2 -->
<div class="border-2">
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 3</button>
</div>



I tried floating the element, expecting to be able to just use margin to add the space, instead resulted in it being still below the object (not what I wanted) and also at the very edge instead of next to the border.
The intended outcome was to have the two groups floating next to each other instead of being below it on the page.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What should this look like?

Sorry about that, not used to stack overflow, hopefully that helped.

You want the border group and border-2 group to be side by side? or the buttons in these containers

Border 2 and 3 should be side by side, not below each other. The buttons are already in the containers with div aren't they?

There is no Border 3. Do you mean you want the two containers next to each other? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display

I just realized this one didn't have three groups like the original. That would be correct, I'll fix that really quick. I have looked on multiple stack overflow questions and none of the answers worked, I did not see that one however, it still doesn't seem to answer my question, borders aren't involved in that one.

Do you need the first group to be next to the second group and not under each other?

Yes that is the expected outcome.

Then this is a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display

You should wrap both divs in another div and display it flex. You can read more about Flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/


html,
body {
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #038253;
}

.border {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
   
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.border-2 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;

  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.border-container {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   gap: 1rem;
}
<h1>Test Site</h1>
<!-- Button Group 1 -->
<div class="border-container">

 <div class="border">
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 3</button>
</div>

<!-- Button Group 2 -->
<div class="border-2">
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button 3</button>
</div>

</div>
   




Running the code snippet in site, it does not work and the first one has lost the border entirely.

Yeah, had a typo, it should work now

After actually adding it to a file, they are being displayed very far apart, and I'm unsure how to change that, was expecting them to be right next to each other.  Flex is something I haven't used before. I'm suspecting my use of margin: auto; might be to blame. To further clarify, I also want them to be centered.
Current fix was to remove margin: auto from both borders and add justify-content: center; to the flex as stated in a Google result.

Yes, updated the code to reflect this, removed the margin auto and made use of the justify-content property of flex. You should check out the CSS Tricks link I added to the solution. Just to confirm, you are okay with the current solution now, right?

Yes, I'll mark this as the answer
